# Not able to scrape a website for HTML?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parsing, jsoup

So I'm trying to get my application to go to website, get the HTML from that website, remove the unnecessary elements from the HTML, and then load the 'content' in my make shift app, because I don't have an API or a feed. I'm using Jsoup and it is able to work if I'm doing the web scraping not in android, but android is not liking it.

```
public class SimpleDiggActivity extends Activity {

private WebView browser;
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

    String url = "http://www.digg.com";
    Document digg;
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    final Button homeDigg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new SimpleWebViewClient());

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    browser.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");

    // progressCircle = ProgressDialog.show(SimpleDiggActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
    final ProgressDialog progressCircle = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressCircle.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressCircle.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressCircle.setCancelable(false);

    try{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Steps down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Document diggTest = Jsoup.connect("http://digg.com/enable/mobile").get();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 Steps down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String diggTitle = diggTest.title();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2 Steps down"    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Document compressed = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(diggTitle);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3 Steps down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        org.jsoup.select.Elements div = diggTest.select("div");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4 Steps down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String divBrow = div.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "5 Steps down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        browser.loadUrl(divBrow);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gave up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String diggBrow = url;
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Sorry if it's messy, I'm just messing around and it's my first time. The Toasts are for me to tell when the code is failing the try and resorting to the catch. When I run it, it doesn't make it past

```
 Document diggTest = Jsoup.connect("http://digg.com/enable/mobile").get();
```

Comment: No errors, it just isn't able to connect or get the HTML from digg.com, I tried it in a regular Java workspace and it worked fine, though.

Comment: I'm presuming you're running this off an emulator, is there a perhaps a permission you have to set to allow outsides connections? (I'm asking, I don't know unfortunately)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> is this in your manifest?

Comment: I am in fact running this off of the emulator, I can try my phone and see if I get different results. and Yes, that is the only permission I have. It can access the internet completely with or without the app.

Comment: On my phone I received the same exact thing, it immediately gives up and moves onto the catch

Comment: what is the exception that you are getting..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar howcome when I use the same code outside of Android, it works though? also this error is regardless of digg.com or digg.com/enable/mobile

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with JSOUP version 1.7.1 and it is working fine at my end. Following is the working code:

```
public class SimpleDiggActivity extends Activity {

    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_digg);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        String url = "http://www.digg.com";
        Document digg;

        // progressCircle = ProgressDialog.show(SimpleDiggActivity.this, "",
        // "Loading...");
        final ProgressDialog progressCircle = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressCircle.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressCircle.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressCircle.setCancelable(false);

        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Steps down",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Document diggTest = Jsoup.connect("http://digg.com/enable/mobile")
                    .get();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 Steps down",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String diggTitle = diggTest.title();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2 Steps down",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Document compressed = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(diggTitle);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3 Steps down",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            org.jsoup.select.Elements div = diggTest.select("div");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4 Steps down",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String divBrow = div.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "5 Steps down",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "data is " + divBrow);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gave up",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String diggBrow = url;
        }
    }
}
```

Following is value of divBrow:

```
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350): data is <div class="site-header-container page-container"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):  <header class="site-header"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):   <h1 class="site-header-logo-container"><a href="/" id="site-header-logo" class="image-replace">Digg</a></h1> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):  </header> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350): </div>
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350): <div id="container" class="page-container"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):  <ul id="top-stories"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):   <li class="story-container story-1" data-content-id="Racz8K" id="story-Racz8K"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):    <div class="story-details"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-kicker">
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):       NO FILTER 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-headline"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <a data-position="0" class="story-link" href="http://www.fastcompany.com/3001994/no-filter-inside-hipstamatics-lost-year-searching-next-killer-social-app" data-content-id="Racz8K"> Inside Hipstamatic’s Lost Year Searching For The Next Killer Social&nbsp;App </a> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-domain"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <div class="story-link-wrapper"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):       <a data-position="0" class="story-link" href="http://www.fastcompany.com/3001994/no-filter-inside-hipstamatics-lost-year-searching-next-killer-social-app" data-content-id="Racz8K">fastcompany.com</a> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <div class="story-actions"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):       <span class="story-action-item story-score"> <span class="story-score-details"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):         <ul class="story-score-details-list"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):          <li class="story-score-thumb-Racz8K story-score-thumb">20</li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):          <li class="story-score-tweets-Racz8K story-score-twitter">402</li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):          <li class="story-score-fb_shares-Racz8K story-score-facebook">72</li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):         </ul> </span> <span class="story-score-Racz8K">494</span> </span> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-image"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <a data-position="0" class="story-link" href="http://www.fastcompany.com/3001994/no-filter-inside-hipstamatics-lost-year-searching-next-killer-social-app" data-content-id="Racz8K"><img src="http://static.digg.com/images/Racz8K_1_www_large_thumb.jpeg" alt="" width="312" height="170" /></a> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-preview">
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      From rooftop bashes and acquisition talks to staff clashes and layoffs, Hipstamatic’s founders and ex-employees describe the startup’s losing struggle to keep pace with Instagram, Facebook, and others in the white-hot photo-sharing space.
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):    </div> </li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):   <li class="story-container story-1" data-content-id="Qa2sP3" id="story-Qa2sP3"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):    <div class="story-details"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-kicker">
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):       PHOTOGRAPHY 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-headline"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <a data-position="1" class="story-link" href="http://lens.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/09/looking-into-the-eyes-of-made-in-china/" data-content-id="Qa2sP3"> Looking Into The Eyes Of 'Made In&nbsp;China' </a> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-domain"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <div class="story-link-wrapper"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):       <a data-position="1" class="story-link" href="http://lens.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/09/looking-into-the-eyes-of-made-in-china/" data-content-id="Qa2sP3">lens.blogs.nytimes.com</a> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <div class="story-actions"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):       <span class="story-action-item story-score"> <span class="story-score-details"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):         <ul class="story-score-details-list"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):          <li class="story-score-thumb-Qa2sP3 story-score-thumb">0</li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):          <li class="story-score-tweets-Qa2sP3 story-score-twitter">252</li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):          <li class="story-score-fb_shares-Qa2sP3 story-score-facebook">411</li> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):         </ul> </span> <span class="story-score-Qa2sP3">663</span> </span> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-image"> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      <a data-position="1" class="story-link" href="http://lens.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/09/looking-into-the-eyes-of-made-in-china/" data-content-id="Qa2sP3"><img src="http://static.digg.com/images/Qa2sP3_1_www_large_thumb.jpeg" alt="" width="312" height="170" /></a> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div> 
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     <div class="story-preview">
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):      In “Faces of Made in China,” a series of typological portraits looking at workers inside six Chinese factories, the photographer Lucas Schifres seeks to consider the otherwise anonymous people who produce our essential possessions by looking directly into their eyes.
10-10 11:58:45.631: D/SimpleDiggActivity(350):     </div>
```

Please try it at your end and let me know how it went.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll keep trying. Basically, I need to be able to grab that div of the container, display it as it would normally look on the mobile digg but just get rid of the header and footer. Yay. Thank you.